# how to filter bad requests inside asyncio loop

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have the following asyncio code:

```
async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url, ssl=False) as response:
        status = response.status
        data = await response.json(content_type='text/html')
        data_length = len(data)
        return {"url": url, "status": status, "data_length": data_length, "data": data}


async def fetch_all(urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=vtheaders) as session:
        tasks = [fetch(url, session) for url in urls]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        return results
```

Which get a list of URLs, and is running them.
specifically, I'm using virustotal API.

Now, I get the following error:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
> 0)

And I was able to track the response from the API request which was error 500 but it wasn't received in a JSON so I guess that's why I get json is empty so decoder is failing...

This is the error:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"> <title>500 Internal Server Error</title> <h1>Internal Server Error</h1> <p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or     there is an error in the application.</p>
```

I don't know how I can avoid this bad URL inside my asyncio loop :(
Any guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if `status` is 200

```
async def fetch(url, session):
    async with session.get(url, ssl=False) as response:
        status = response.status
        if status == 200:
            data = await response.json(content_type='text/html')
        else:
            data = '{}'
        data_length = len(data)
        return {"url": url, "status": status, "data_length": data_length, "data": data}
```